# How do I get the Alias Path/Node Alias in C# Kentico 12 MVC

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc, kentico-api

I am using the standard `DocumentHelper.GetDocuments` to find a page, and for top level pages, the `.WhereEquals("NodeAlias", pageAlias)` is working fine, where pageAlias is along the lines of "Test-Page".

Once I start resolving child pages (so `pageAlias = "Test-Page/Another-Page"`) DocumentHelper is returning `null`.

I am wondering if I can see the NodeAlias for the pages in C# somehow?
This should allow me to map the pages better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"NodeAlias" is typically just the URL friendly alias for the page - "Another-page" for example. I believe you may be looking for "NodeAliasPath" which will give you the full alias path - "/Test-Page/Another-Page"